# Was für eine Imperativform ist die in „Helfe einem Obdachlosen!“?

Tags: conjugation, imperative

Die Frage ist zu elementar. Aber ich kann noch nicht verstehen warum sagt man

> *Helfe* einem Obdachlosen!

statt einer der folgenden Varianten:

> { *Hilf* | *Helfen Sie* | *Helft* } einem Obdachlosen!

Comment: Ich erinnere mich an ein Adventure in den 80ern, bei dem fehlerhafterweise "Nehme" anstelle von "Nimm" hinterlegt war. Ich brauchte zwei Wochen und ein disassembly, bis ich verstanden hatte, dass ich "Nehme Krone" eingeben musste. Urgh!

Comment: Und ich kann dazu nur immer wieder den hier verlinken: http://www.spiegel.de/netzwelt/web/grossbild-406186-596249.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tendency of speakers of German to forget using the “irregular” imperatives, i.e., that of strong verbs with e as a stem vowel (geben, helfen, werfen, …)¹. Instead they form the imperative, as if these verbs were regular. For example, instead of using *gib* as an imperative of *geben,* they use *geb(e)* (compare to the weak verb *leben,* whose correct imperative is *leb(e)*). *Helfe* is one of these forms.

In spoken language, the difference between the two cases (e.g., *gib* vs. *geb*) is difficult to hear and to distinguish from sloppy pronunciation. Therefore it’s difficult to say, how frequently this happens.

Though there is no authority on such matters for German, this is generally considered wrong. A possible reason why irregularities are forgotten here is that the imperative has got out of use in some of its primary applications and been replaced by the “subjunctive of politeness” – especially in written language. General appeals (as I guees your example to be) are actually one of the few remaining cases where the use of the written imperative would not be considered impolite (recipe-style instructions being another one).

To summarise, it should be “Hilf” and not ”Helfe”.

---

¹ I am  aware that there are other ways to learn or explain how the imperative is formed, but apparently, this is what happens inside the head of most speakers of Germans.

Answer (score 6):

Tja, vor einigen Jahrzehnten hätte man schlichtweg gesagt: Das ist falsch. (Denn starke Verben, die in der 2./3. Person Singular einen Vokalwechsel zu *i* haben, bilden auch den Imperativ Singular mit diesem *i*, und ohne Endung.) Vermutlich werden Deutschlehrer und Korrektoren das auch immer noch so sehen.

In der alltäglichen Sprache allerdings ist diese Imperativform praktisch ausgestorben. Es mag regionale Unterschiede geben; aber da, wo ich mich aufhalte, hört man nur die regelmäßige Bildung, also den Infinitivstamm (selten mit *-e*, das ja auch bei den schwachen Verben meistens fehlt):

> Nun helf mir mal! Seh dir an, was hier steht! Nehm dir was davon, aber geb Sarah auch etwas ab!

Irgendwann wird die gehobene Sprache dem folgen (müssen).

Interessanterweise hat die Imperativbildung im 17./18. Jahrhundert geschwankt, es gibt bei den damaligen Schriftstellern Belege für beide Formen. Erst danach hat sich die Sprachgemeinschaft auf die Sonderbehandlung bestimmter starker Verben festgelegt, bis in jüngerer Zeit die Entwicklung wieder in die Gegenrichtung ging.

Comment: Zur Zeit entsprechen beide Varianten pauschal nicht der Sprechwirklichkeit. Aus deinem Beispiel: `sehen` wird auf jeden Fall, `nehmen` in den meisten Fällen stark gebeugt. Nur `helfen` und `geben` dürften überwiegend schwach gebeugt werden.

Comment: *"Gib das her!"* - *"Nun hilf mir doch!"* - "überwiegend schwach" und "praktisch ausgestorben" kann man so nicht sagen.

Comment: Nach meiner Erfahrung eben doch. Ich habe schon lange keinen starken Imperativ in freier Wildbahn mehr gehört.

Comment: @Toscho: Hier ein paar Suchanfragen mit Belegen für den Imperativ „seh“: [`"seh dir den"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22seh+dir+den%22), [`"seh dir das"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22seh+dir+das%22), [`"seh dich um"`](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22seh+dich+um%22).

Comment: Und zumindestens in den ersten beiden Fällen liefert die analoge Anfrage mit *sieh* deutlich mehr Ergebnisse, im zweiten autokorrigiert Google einen sogar; im dritten Fall liegen beide interessanterweise gleichauf. Im [N-Gram](http://tinyurl.com/pqeyljq) (was natürlich nur die überwiegend lektorierte Schriftsprache erfasst) nimmt der relative Anteil der »schwachen« Imperative sogar ab.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich wollte in erster Linie widerlegen, daß von _sehen_ „auf jeden Fall“ der starke Imperativ verwendet werde. – Im allgemeinen ist das mit den vorhandenen Korpora leider schwer zu fassen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ja, anscheinend tritt der schwache Imperativ inzwischen auch bei `sehen` auf. Google scheint doch mehr Leute zu kennen, als ich. Wer hätte das geglaubt.